# How to retrieve DOM objects inside angular2 directives

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to retrieve the element from my directive and do some css change on it. But it is always telling me `nativeElement is undefined`

I tried both ways:

1. @ViewChild
2. @ContentChild

Both of them are not working.

My parent html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 module_style" id="module-wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="left-alignment">
            <b><i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Market Category: </b>
            {{item.marketCategory}}
        </p>
        <p class="right-alignment" id="moduleCog" [moduleOpt]="item">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </p>
        <module-modal #moduleModal [data]="item"></module-modal>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12"><p class="left-alignment">{{item.source}} <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{item.target}}</p></div>
</div>
```

Child html: "module-modal"

```
<div id="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
      <p>Hear me roar.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, ViewChild, HostListener, OnInit, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[moduleOpt]'
})

export class ModuleOptDirective implements OnInit{
    showModal: boolean = false;
    @Input('moduleOpt') moduleOpt: any;
    @ContentChild('moduleModal') moduleModal: ElementRef;
    //@ViewChild('moduleModal') moduleModal: ElementRef;
    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    showDetails(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(this.moduleOpt);
        this._renderer.setElementClass(this.moduleModal.nativeElement, 'modal-animate', true);

    }

}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

```
this._renderer.setElementClass(this.moduleModal.nativeElement, 'modal-animate', true);
```

`this.moduleModal.nativeElement` is a wrong usage of `nativeElement`
Turns out `this.moduleModal` is not null...
instead use `this.moduleModal.nativeElement` I should have used the following:

```
...
export class ModuleOptionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('item') item: any;
    //@ViewChild('moduleModal') moduleModal: ElementRef

    constructor(
        private _renderer: Renderer,
        private _elem: ElementRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    showDetails(event) {
        this._renderer.setElementClass(this._elem.nativeElement, 'modal-animate', true);

    }
}
```

this will only select the DOM object whichever applied this directive.